# Service Subscribe MQTT on Python Stop

Tags: python, mqtt, systemd, paho

I made service python on systemd for running subcribe mqtt forever but I have some issue when check in morning subscribe not running. This my code running

```
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe
from store_Sensor_Data_to_DB import Save_data

def on_message_print(client, userdata, message):
    print("%s %s" % (message.topic, message.payload))
    Save_data(message.topic, message.payload)


try:
    subscribe.callback(on_message_print, "a/#", hostname="hosname", keepalive=60)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "exiting"
    client.disconnect()
    client.loop_stop()
```

And this my service code

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have some publish topic a/ping with crontab one hour at a time to make service not disconnect but still disconnect when check in morning. Whats wrong with my script and please tell me if you know something wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Ignore the systemd service, what error do you get when you just run the script at the console

Comment: Also `client.disconnect()` and `client.loop_stop()` will do nothing because there is no client variable in scope at that point

Comment: I haven't error at console but if no publish on topic it will disconnect and stop subscribe